# Adicionar um valor em um objeto JSON

Tags: javascript, json, objetos

Como eu poderia adicionar uma cadeia de valores em um objeto **JSON**?

Por exemplo:

```
var a = 12;
var b = 3;

var obj = {
 c: 11,
 d:22
}
console.log(obj);
```

Como eu poderia aplicar **a** e **b**, dentro da minha variável **obj** para que se tornem parte deste objeto JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vcoê pode adicionar uma propriedade ao objeto `obj` com os valores de `a` e `b`, mas note que ao faze-lo, você estará atribuindo uma copia do valor, então modificações à na variavel não serão refletidas no `obj` e vice-versa.

```js
var a = 12;
var b = 3;

var obj = {
 c: 11,
 d:22
}

obj.a = a;
obj.b = b

console.log(obj);

a = 17;

//obj.a continua com o valor 12
console.log(obj);
```

se precisar que alterações nas propriedades no objeto sejam refletidas nas variaveis e vice-versa, você deve definir um `get` e `set` para a propriedade do `obj`

```js
var a = 12;
var b = 3;

var obj = {
 c: 11,
 d:22
}

Object.defineProperty(obj, "a", {
  get: function () { return a; },
  set: function (value) { a = value; },
  enumerable: true
});

Object.defineProperty(obj, "b", {
  get: function () { return b; },
  set: function (value) { b = value; },
  enumerable: true
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

a = 17;

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

obj.a = 12;

console.log(a);
```

agora se você tiver dois objetos, pode usar o método `Object.assign` para meclar os dois ou mais objetos.

```js
var base = { a: 12, b: 7 };
var objA = { c: 16, d: 4 };
var objB = { e: 13, f: 9 };

Object.assign(base, objA, objB);

console.log(base, objA, objB);

objA.c = 17;

//base.c continua com o valor 16
console.log(base, objA, objB);
```

Comment: então caso eu tenha n valores, eu teria que realizar um laço de repetição para setar cada valor?

Comment: sim, você terá que fazer isto para cada variavel. porém existe uma forma de meclar objetos usando o `Object.assign`, adicionei um exemplo na resposta.

Comment: vc é foda cara, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = 12;
var b = 3;

var obj = {
 c: 11,
 d:22
}

obj["a"] = a;
```

Segue exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/oo6fodmd/